# Is there a way to disable the end user from entering URL's with selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The goal is a locked-in end system.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.fullscreen_window()
driver.get("https://google.com/")
```

This opens a fullscreen window but still allows users to enter URL's by hovering the mouse near the top of the screen. Is there a way to permanently hide the URL bar? Alternatively, is there a way to disable entering a URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kiosk mode will disable all GUI elements.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

option = Options()
option.add_argument("--kiosk")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=option)
driver.get("https://google.com/")
```